# Issue looping through database and showing results php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I am trying to loop through my database and then shown all user names.
Unfortunately I have tried many different ways but can not get it to work.
I am currently trying this

```
  <?php  
   $result= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users");
 while($userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $userRow['user_name'];
 }
 ?>
```

The issue is that I am getting this error and can not work out how to get this working.
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

I am able to show a single row using

```
<?php print($userRow['user_name']); ?>
```

But I can not work out how to loop through every user in my 'user' table

Comment: give connection object as a first parameter

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass first argument as Connection object you have to pass in `mysqli_query()` function.

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
```

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

you have first create link like this

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

and then you have use the link to query the database like this

```
$result= mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users");
```